# Get Data between two different Date with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Table : (Employee)

[image: Data]

I need to get Data Between two Days I'm using the following query to get data between two dates

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Price ((DATE('2020-01-01') BETWEEN DATE(start_date) AND DATE(end_date)) OR (DATE('2020-01-03') BETWEEN DATE(start_date) AND DATE(end_date)) OR (DATE(start_date) >= DATE('2020-07-03')) AND DATE(end_date) <= DATE('2020-07-03'));
```

I Got the following Result :

[image: REsult]

But I Expect the Following result

[image: excpect]

So, How can i get my expected result data in mysql

Comment: Your query has nothing to do with the data you have provided.

Comment: Do you want a row per date?, If yes, can you please check cross apply?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks i will check

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal Yes I want row per date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems to have nothing to do with your sample data.

Based on your data, you seem to need to generate the dates.  You can do this using a recursive CTE and then `join`:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date('2020-01-01') as dte
      union all
      select dte + interval 1 day
      from dates
      where dte < date('2020-01-04')
     )
select d.dte, e.end_date, e.employeename
from employee e join
     dates d
     on d.dte between e.start_date and e.end_date
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de2d4138137f901847037a5b563d182c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: But you are hard coding dates in CTE. May be a function would be good with same CTE and then we do a cross apply?...Or we should use MIN of start date and MAX of end date in CTE

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal it's like report process i not use this in application but if you have any better approach please share with me. it's useful for all

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal . . . Well, MySQL doesn't support `cross apply`, so that wouldn't apply.  There is no need for a separate function.  And MySQL doesn't even support table-valued functions.  So that doesn't seem like a useful suggestion.